# Short way of making many beans depend-on one bean

Tags: java, spring

When using database migrations, I obviously want none of the DAOs to be usable before the migrations are run.

At the moment I'm declaring *a lot* of DAOs, all having a `depends-on=databaseMigrator` property. I find this troubling, especially since it's error prone.

Is there a more compact way of doing this?

---

Notes:

- [the depends-on attribute is not 'inherited' from parent beans](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5467);
- I am not using Hibernate or JPA so I can't make the sessionFactory bean `depend-on` the migrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try writing a class that implements the [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) interface to automatically register the dependencies for you:

**Warning:** This class has not been compiled.

```
public class DatabaseMigratorDependencyResolver implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        String[] beanNames = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);

            // Your job is here:
            // Feel free to make use of the methods available from the BeanDefinition class (http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html)
            boolean isDependentOnDatabaseMigrator = ...;

            if (isDependentOnDatabaseMigrator) {
                beanFactory.registerDependentBean("databaseMigrator", beanName);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You could then include a bean of this class alongside all your other beans.

```
<bean class="DatabaseMigratorDependencyResolver"/>
```

Spring will automatically run it before it starts initiating the rest of the beans.

Comment: Nobody liked my solution, so I'll pick yours as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I do this on application start-up.  The schema version that the application requires is compiled into the application as part of the build process.  It is also stored in the database and updated by the database migration scripts.

On application start-up, the app checks that the schema version in the database is what it expects and if not, aborts immediately with a clear error message.

In a normal Java program, this happens right at the start of the main method.

In a webapp, it's performed by the app's ServletContextListener and is the first thing it does when the servlet context is created.

That's saved my (apps') bacon several times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a Spring solution since all my datasources are already declared there.

Comment: I'm sure you could use Spring to implement this. Whether it actually helps in this case is another question.

Comment: Whether using Spring would help? It certainly does by keeping the data source definitions unitary and _not_ suprising the developer by adding components outside Spring.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a simple `ForwardingDataSource` class which appears in the context files as:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="xxx.ForwardingDataSource" depends-on="databaseMigrator">
   <property name="delegate">
      <!-- real data source here -->
   </property>
</bean>
```

If find it less elegant than [Adam Paynter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959547/short-way-of-making-many-beans-depend-on-one-bean/960897#960897), but clearer.