# Spring MVC Initializing an object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

In my SpringMVC project I need a certain tactic to call a class which does parse a xml file which does own my RMI server ip & port & the url must be relative to servletContext url :

```
HttpServletRequest request;    
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/LABLAB/RMI-Config.xml")
```

I want to load these classes when I start my application in tomcat not when I call a Controller Class because my application depend to my RMI so before anything else I have to parse my file & using the IP & PORT fields to start connecting to my RMI & then call the rmi method to do some stuffs later on ...

now

how I'm gonna do it ? please tell me how I can initialize an instance of HttpServletRequest & give an intial value when I'm not on the Controller classes as well .

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Spring, then you can create a class and implement [IntializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html). If you want to get hold of `ServletContext` you can simple use `@Autowired` annotation in your initializing bean. For e.g.:

```
@Component
public class SomeBean implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;   

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
       String path = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/LABLAB/RMI-Config.xml");
       //do something.
    }
}
```

As per docs:

> IntializingBean - Interface to be implemented by beans that need to
>   react once all their properties have been set by a BeanFactory.

Or take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098995/call-method-on-apache-cxf-initialiaze/12109443#12109443) how to do this using `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: can you please refer to this question ? I used your method but that didn't work for me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172521/error-fetching-servletcontext-inside-a-class

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `ServletContextListener` interface and refer to it from your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>InitializingListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The interface has a `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` method, in which you can call `sce.getServletContext()`, so you don't need a `HttpServletRequest`.

If this doesn't work out, because you also need to access some of your Spring beans from the initializing class, then forget about implementing the `ServletContextListener` interface, and do the following instead:

1. Instantiate your initialization class via Spring (make a bean of that type).
2. Make the class implement `ServletContextAware`. This will cause Spring to inject the `ServletContext` into your class.
3. Define an init method on that bean (use the `init-method` bean attribute, or define a `@PostConstruct` annotated method)
4. Make all your Controller beans depend on the initializing bean by using the `depends-on` bean attribute. As a result, the initialaizing bean will be created before any Controller bean.

Without the last step, it cannot be guaranteed that your controllers won't start processing requests before the initialization bean finishes its work. However, specifying the `depends-on` attribute on each and every controller bean is also problematic, especially that they are usually created by applying the `@Controller` annotation instead of xml configuration. A nice workaround is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/959547/1276804).

Comment: can you please refer to this question ? I used your method but that didn't work for me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172521/error-fetching-servletcontext-inside-a-class